# type of + (singular noun) defined as (plural)

Tags: expressions

Please, can anyone help me with this? Is it accurate to say the following:

there *is* a *type of snake* called "*The Cobra snakes*", and *those* snakes .....etc.

In other words, when saying "*type of snake*" it sounds like you're describing something singular, but is it ok to demonstrate the type as a plural?; like when I said "called "**The ***Cobra snakes*****", and *those* snakes .....etc."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say just 'the snake' here because 
the definite article can be used with a *singular* noun to indicate that it represents a *whole* *species* or *class*.

For example:

> ‘they placed the African elephant on their endangered list’
>   (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/)

Comment: thanks a lot, so can I say it like this?
There is a type of snake called "The Cobra Snake", and those snakes .....etc.